# QGIS Network Analysis: QgsLineVectorLayerDirector.makeGraph(), attribute type QVector not available

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt, pyqt4, network-analysis

relates to QGIS 2.14.6LTR on Win10, PyQt Version 4.10.2

When trying to `makeGraph()` on `QgsLineVectorLayerDirector` as described in the "QGIS Network analysis library" documentation (http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html) like

```
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(vl, -1, '', '', '', 3)
#[...]
psource = f_source.geometry()
ptarget = f_target.geometry()
#each assumed to be of type QgsPoint 
#director has added a QgsDistanceArcProperter
#builder is a QgsGraphBuiler
#[...]    
director.makeGraph(builder, [psource, ptarget])
```

I get an error message `QgsLineVectorLayerDirector.makeGraph(QgsGraphBuilderInterface, list-of-QgsPoint): argument 2 has unexpected type 'list' See log for more details`

Isn't the list internaly converted to `QVector` which is expected by `makeGraph()` https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLineVectorLayerDirector.html#af14ff34e31a2860edd156090c0f746ef

What should I pass to `makeGraph()` instead of my list?

**ADD/UPDATE:**
I tried

```
[...]
tp = QVector()
tp.append(psource)
tp.append(ptarget)
tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, tp)
[...]
```

but `name 'QVector' is not defined See log for more details`. Isn't this imported with `from PyQt4.QtCore import *` ?

**ADD:** Obviously not:
[image]

Refer to also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746241/pyqt4-convert-list-to-qvector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ekhumoro gives following answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746241/pyqt4-convert-list-to-qvector:

"PyQt has never wrapped the `QVector` class, and it's unlikely that there will ever be a reason for doing so.

The `QgsLineVectorLayerDirector.makeGraph` method is expecting a list of `QgsPoint` instances. So presumably either (1) the list you're passing in doesn't contain objects that are all of the right type, or (2) the `Qgs` library you're using is broken."

Related to my above question, the solution is that

```
psource = f_source.geometry()
ptarget = f_target.geometry()
```

return `QgsGeometry` and not `QgsPoint` as desired, so correct ist would be

```
psource = f_source.geometry().asPoint()
ptarget = f_target.geometry().asPoint()
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong type of argument:

```
void    makeGraph (QgsGraphBuilderInterface *builder, const QVector< QgsPoint > &additionalPoints, QVector< QgsPoint > &tiedPoints)
```

Second argument should be QVector type, not a list.

And if you cant import:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVector
```

that means your PyQt is 4.6 or below. You should update it to 4.7+.

Comment: I'll check this out, but how to update a) Case of installed qgis from exe  Installer or b) Case of installed from osgeo4w Installer?

Comment: I have no idea how it works on Windows.

Comment: `QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR` gives me `4.10.2` wich I think is `4.7+.`